# Cleaning a mouth retainer

Tags: cleaning

I got my braces removed about a year ago and I wear my retainers every night now. I was advised to gently wash my retainers in cold water. However, doing so does not clean the retainer of plaque.

1. I have tried brushing it with my tooth brush but it doesn't clean it properly. Now, the plaque is just building into a think over-coating.
2. I tried soaking it in a Denture Cleanser tablet
3. I tried soaking it over-night in a cup of listerine and then seeing if it brushed off.

None of these seemed to work, so any advice on what is the best way to clean it?

**EDIT:** Result of @FlatBanana's answer: I soaked my retainer for about 8 hours in a cup of water and a table spoon of baking soda. When I pulled them out, although they were not completely clean, brushing them with some toothpaste made the plaque come out much more easily. So, for now, this is the best solution I have found so far.

Comment: Tried asking your dentist/orthodontist?  I bet they have additional suggestions...

Comment: They suggested to regularly wash with cold water; however, little by little, more plaque (that gets missed during the daily morning wash) accumulates.

Comment: @Christian Ask them again, but this time tell them about your real concerns with the plaque.

Comment: I have this same problem! I hope we can find something that works! 
On a side note, you can use toothpaste and your toothbrush, then use your fingernails to remove the rest. This can; however, be rather time consuming and doesn't always remove everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using baking soda and castile soap.  Whenever you are not wearing them soak them in distilled water with a little bit of baking soda, the castile soap will help to give them a fresher smell.

After soaking, I would suggest you brush them to remove any leftover baking soda.

Comment: I shall try this and post results. :)

Comment: @Christian Okay Christian, you've had over 4 years... what were your results?

Comment: It removes any recent/new buildup. But doesn't remove the buildup from a months ago. On the other hand, dentists do have some sort of chemical solution that will clean the retainer. completely. Don't remember the name but something like that does exist.